# How does the Javascript '>' operator compare characters with a space?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand this expression:

```
((ch = stream.getChar()) > ' ')
```

Here, `getChar()` gets a character. How does this greater-than comparision operator check if any char is greater than an empty space?

Is this possible?

Comment: Well now that the things are explained you have to tell us a bit more of the background of all this, I'm curious to know why someone would check that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An empty space has a character code. Even though it doesn't look like much, it still has a value. So does the character taken from the stream. Comparing the character codes of these values is what produces the output.

Comment: when comparing 2 strings this is their character codes that are compared?

Comment: Yes, When comparing strings is compares their character code.

Comment: so 'file_2013_03_01.txt' >  'file_2013_02_01.txt' because the char code of the first string is higher than the second? How is it even calculated...

Comment: You can check the character code of characters in JavaScript strings using the `charCodeAt` method. E.g. `" ".charCodeAt(0);// 32 "a".charCodeAt(0);// 97`.

Comment: yes but what if this is a string? There's no charcode for an entire string. The comparing behaviour is different if this is a 1 character string than a multiple characters string?

Comment: And in reference to your example, `"file_2013_02".charCodeAt(11);` returns `50`, whilst `"file_2013_03".charCodeAt(11);` returns 51.

Comment: @Sebas The string comparison is iterative: char by char.

Comment: @Sebas: it compares them as if sorting in alphabetical order, or as if sorting numbers. There's no single digit that represents 1000 or 1001 either, but 1000 < 1001.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much you guys that was great! so the alphabetical order when comparing string is a coincidence. If 'a' had a higher charcode than 'b' we would have 'a' > 'b'. Mystery solved

Comment: @Sebas: correct, although I think character codes were intentionally assigned in alphabetical order, possibly to allow sorting and comparison like this.

Comment: @Sebas Well "a" in ascii is 97. "b" is, obviously 98. Because the ordering of ASCII is alphabetical, so is the comparison.

Comment: Of course, by coincidence I meant that there is no incidence in between facts. Obviously programmers are not totally crazy and did it on purpose. @ChrisCooney: I don't think this is relevant. They could have put 97 instead of 98. This is what I mean by coincidence. They just didn't do it for obvious reasons...

Comment: @Sebas. Correction my friend. Programmers are totally crazy. We just pull it off very well. Also be sure to mark the correct answer, for future readers!

Comment: @ChrisCooney Besides it works for English language, in some languages (e.g. in Russian) there are letters placed not in a way they should go. So such comparison should be used with caution if different alphabets exploited.

Comment: Course, well hopefully they will. :)

Answer (score 9):

Let's take a gander at the [language specification](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.2) (the algorithm itself is described in [here](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5)) (do note that it defines `<`, but the `>` operator simply flips the resulting value).

What the operator does is try to convert both operands to primitive types, with a preference for numbers:

```
2. a. Let py be the result of calling ToPrimitive(y, hint Number).
2. b. Let px be the result of calling ToPrimitive(x, hint Number).
```

In our case, `x === stream.getChar()` and `y === ' '`. Since both of the operands are primitive strings already, that results in the original values (`px = x, py = y`), and we move on to:

```
4. Else, both px and py are Strings
```

Now it does checks to see if any of the operands are prefixes of the other, for example:

```
'abc' > 'abcd' // false
'foo' > 'foobar' // false
```

Which is relevant if `getChar()` results in a space, since the space is a prefix of itself:

```
' ' > ' ' // false
```

We move on, to finding the first character in `x` and `y` who're on the same position in the strings, but are different characters:

> Let k be the smallest nonnegative integer such that the character at position k within px is different from the character at position k within py. (There must be such a k, for neither String is a prefix of the other.)

(e.g., `'efg'` and `'efh'`, we want `g` and `h`)

The characters we've found are then converted to their integer values:

```
Let m be the integer that is the code unit value for the character at position k within px.
Let n be the integer that is the code unit value for the character at position k within py.
```

And finally, a comparison is made:

```
If m < n, return true. Otherwise, return false.
```

And that's how it's compared to the space.

---

tl;dr It converts both arguments to their code-unit integer representations, and compares that.

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript strings are compared in alphabetical order. These expressions are true:

```
 'abacus' <= 'calculator'
 'abacus' < 'abate'
```

Comment: However `'#b' < '~a'`. Alphabetic order doesn't cover it.

Answer (score 2):

In most (if not all) programming languages, characters are represented internally by a number. When you do equality/greater-than/less-than checks what you're actually checking is the underlying number.

hence in JS:

```
alert('c' > 'b'); // alerts true
alert('a' > 'b'); // alerts false
```

A space character also has a numeric representation, therefore the check is a valid one.

Comment: But this starts getting weird when you get into UTF-8 land right? Is it possible to compare international alphabetical characters?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai In general, no. Comparing just code point values (the characters' numeric representations) might work for some languages and for some subset of codepoints, but in general Unicode string comparisons should use the Unicode Collation recommendations (or more likely in practice, find a language feature or library to compare by collation order).

Answer (score 1):

`[string] > [string]` will compare the character(s) by their representative values (see [ASCII Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII))

Comment: He is asking about the > operator.

Comment: @dreadlock: thanks - you're right! missed that. I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Characters are stored in the computer's memory as a number (usually a byte or two).

Each character has a unique identifying number.

By checking if a character is greater than space, you actually comapare their place in a table.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII for more.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link, it'll explain how the comparison works on JS: http://javascript.about.com/od/decisionmaking/a/des02.htm
Basically, you're comparing the ASCII value of each character to the ASCII value of the blank space, which is also, a character and therefore, has a corresponding ASCII value.